# Extract zip file to different location without Terminal

Tags: zip, compression

Without third-party software, is there a way to extract a zip file to a different location without using Terminal?
I realize I could use `unzip file.zip -d /path/to/destination`, but I'd love to do it just by dragging and dropping with a keyboard modifier or something.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try throwing your terminal script into automators run shell script and saving as a service, then you just right click on the file and select the new service and it'll extract to your chosen destination.

there are a few other answers here
https://discussions.apple.com/message/17831395#17831395

I also found a very interesting tool today called [Keka](http://www.kekaosx.com/en/), which is fantastic for creating seperate zip files from one large folder. It has an option to save to a new folder, perhaps this could help.